# NPM - Can't install packages

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I inherited a `React` project and after getting the latest code it failed to run - the previous developer isn't available. So, with no experience, I got on with it

Here's a list of the thing I did:

- Updated `Node` to latest
- Updated `NPM` to latest
- Updated `VS Code` to latest
- Removed `package-lock.json`
- Ran a bunch of `npm<whatever>` commands that are littered all over    internet
- The *coup de grâce* was when I deleted all the packages from    `node_modules`

So, now I can't even get `npm install --verbose` to work.  *It just hangs and gives no feedback*.  I can't reinstall `Node` because the jokers here got us locked-down.

What can I do to install the packages?  Am I doomed?

UPDATE:  I disconnected from the network and went on the company wifi and `npm install` worked.  How can that be?

Comment: What OS? Can you run other NPM commands? Ie, "npm --version"?

Comment: `Ran a bunch of npm<whatever> commands that are littered all over internet` - this is probably where things started going wrong. Can you go back to the original versions of Node and NPM that the project was built with?

Comment: @SteveBennett...it's Windows and all other commands seemed to work. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Narm...you're probably right, but I'm too far in the weeds.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Updating NPM shouldn't cause issues, but running a code on a _very_ different version of Node could, so as @Narm said, fall back to original versions (`package.json`, may declare an `engine` version BTW). Also, since changing network adapter changed the issue: try `npm cache clear` (another `npm<whatever>` thingie, but this one can't harm) then reinstall packages. Then go see the "jokers" (LAN admin guy blocking everything?) for them to look in the logs if anything got explicitly rejected by the router. Finally: _coup de grâce_ = mercy (killing) blow. _gras_ = fat. Pardon my French. ;)

Comment: @StockOverflaw...maybe I can apply coup de gras to the jokers :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to your update - probably your machine is behind the company proxy, that's why npm cannot get packages. To fix this find your proxy address, and after this run in terminal:

```
npm config set proxy http://yourproxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://yourproxy.company.com:8080
```

I found this method on https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/, works very good.